# How can I create two level nested JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, nested

My data looks like this

```
ENTITY,MEASUREMENT_DATE,CHART_VALUE,PARAM
143,2019/03/08 10:21:21 PM,0.047353,param1
143,2019/03/08 10:21:21 PM,40.25,param2
160,2019/03/08 10:57:18 AM,0.066874,param1
160,2019/03/06 4:24:31 PM,38,param2
143,2019/03/06 10:00:41 PM,0.01707,param1
143,2019/03/09 1:04:32 AM,35.25,param2
160,2019/03/06 4:24:31 PM,0.048042,param1
143,2019/03/07 12:09:38 AM,0,param1
160,2019/03/08 10:57:18 AM,42.25,param2
143,2019/03/09 1:04:32 AM,0.012104,param1
143,2019/03/06 10:00:41 PM,41.75,param2
143,2019/03/07 12:09:38 AM,36.5,param2
```

and desired output should look like this:

```
{
    "143": {
        "param1": {
            "MEASUREMENT_DATE": 
            "CHART_VALUE":
         }, 
         "param2": {
           "MEASUREMENT_DATE": 
            "CHART_VALUE": 
         },
     },
     "160": {
        "param1": {
            "MEASUREMENT_DATE": 
            "CHART_VALUE":
         }, 
         "param2": {
           "MEASUREMENT_DATE": 
            "CHART_VALUE": 
         },
     }, 
}
```

I have tried this code, but I still don't get the list as grouped by parameter:

```
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    r = DictReader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r]

    groups = []
    uniquekeys = []

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: ( r['PARAM'])):
        groups.append({
            "group": k,
            "user": [{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in ['PARAM']} for d in list(g)]
        })
        uniquekeys.append(k)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fundamental issue where you cannot use the dictionary structure in your example.

As an example, you have two rows with '143' and 'param1'. A dictionary cannot hold multiple values at the same key. That leaves two choices (I think). Either you want to store an array of results at each location, or you want to have a way to pick one value to store at that key (e.g. the latest value by date).

Nonetheless, this should get you started. This is the solution where you store all values for a key:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pprint import pformat
import csv
try:
  from io import StringIO
except:
  from StringIO import StringIO


data = '''ENTITY,MEASUREMENT_DATE,CHART_VALUE,PARAM
143,2019/03/08 10:21:21 PM,0.047353,param1
143,2019/03/08 10:21:21 PM,40.25,param2
160,2019/03/08 10:57:18 AM,0.066874,param1
160,2019/03/06 4:24:31 PM,38,param2
143,2019/03/06 10:00:41 PM,0.01707,param1
143,2019/03/09 1:04:32 AM,35.25,param2
160,2019/03/06 4:24:31 PM,0.048042,param1
143,2019/03/07 12:09:38 AM,0,param1
160,2019/03/08 10:57:18 AM,42.25,param2
143,2019/03/09 1:04:32 AM,0.012104,param1
143,2019/03/06 10:00:41 PM,41.75,param2
143,2019/03/07 12:09:38 AM,36.5,param2
'''

class JsonBuilder(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.result = {}

  def ingest_row(self, row):
    primary_key, mdate, value, param = row
    if primary_key not in self.result:
      self.result[primary_key] = {}

    if param not in self.result[primary_key]:
      self.result[primary_key][param] = []

    self.result[primary_key][param].append({ 
        "MEASUREMENT_DATE": mdate,
         "CHART_VALUE": value })
  def __str__(self):
    return pformat(self.result)

builder = JsonBuilder()
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(data))
next(reader, None) #skip header
for row in reader:
 builder.ingest_row(row)
print(builder)
```

The output:

```
{'143': {'param1': [{'CHART_VALUE': '0.047353',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/08 10:21:21 PM'},
                    {'CHART_VALUE': '0.01707',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/06 10:00:41 PM'},
                    {'CHART_VALUE': '0',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/07 12:09:38 AM'},
                    {'CHART_VALUE': '0.012104',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/09 1:04:32 AM'}],
         'param2': [{'CHART_VALUE': '40.25',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/08 10:21:21 PM'},
                    {'CHART_VALUE': '35.25',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/09 1:04:32 AM'},
                    {'CHART_VALUE': '41.75',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/06 10:00:41 PM'},
                    {'CHART_VALUE': '36.5',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/07 12:09:38 AM'}]},
 '160': {'param1': [{'CHART_VALUE': '0.066874',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/08 10:57:18 AM'},
                    {'CHART_VALUE': '0.048042',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/06 4:24:31 PM'}],
         'param2': [{'CHART_VALUE': '38',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/06 4:24:31 PM'},
                    {'CHART_VALUE': '42.25',
                     'MEASUREMENT_DATE': '2019/03/08 10:57:18 AM'}]}}
```

Comment: thanks, it's exactly what i need!!! 

one question:
is there a way to set variable not based on the column order?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I'm thinking it might be regarding column interpretation based on the header, rather than presuming the column order? If so, using csv.DictReader is where I would move towards